# Show a set is a subspace of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Show a set is a subspace of vector space, should I prove X(0)=Y(0)?

[image]

Comment: No. You should shows that if you add two functions from $U$ that the result is also in $U$, and that if you take a function $f$ in $U$ and create the new function $x \mapsto \lambda f(x)$, then the new function is also in $U$. I have no idea what you mean by $X(0)= Y(0)$.

Comment: "$X(0)=Y(0)$" makes no sense here.  $X$ are $Y$ are sets, not functions.

Answer (score 1):

You must prove:

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\;0\in U\;,\;\;\text{and here "zero" is the neutral element in}\;\;\mathcal F(X,\Bbb F)\;,\;\text{i.e. the zero function}\\
(2)&\;\;\;f,g\in U\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb F\implies af+bg\in U\;,\;\text{meaning}:\;\;af(u)+bg(u)=0\;\;\;\forall\;u\in U\end{align*}$$

Try to show the above two points and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

To show that an object is a subspace, you first must determine if it is a subset (this is usually easy). Then you must show that it is a vector space in its own right. You can do this from the axioms, but if you have already discussed the useful theorem that [[a subset $S$ is a subspace if $ax+by\in S$ whenever $x,y\in S$ and $a,b\in \mathbb F$]] then you should use that.